# data.table column subsetting returns column names, not columns themselves

Tags: r, data.table, character, subset, numeric

I'm processing some of the CES PUMD data and am using functions from the Census Bureau's `cepumd` package. I got a strange error running their `ce_mean()` function and was working inside of the source code trying to troubleshoot.

```
 if (length(setdiff(sapply(ce_data[, (check_cols)], class), "numeric")) > 0) {
    stop(
      stringr::str_c(
        "'finlwt21', all replicate weight variables, i.e., 'wtrep01' to",
        "'wtrep44', and the 'cost' variable must be numeric.",
        sep = " "
      )
    )
  }
```

This if statement was throwing my error.

`ce_data` is your standard itbi table from the PUMD interview file, in data.table format. `check cols` is defined as follows:

```
wtrep_vars <-stringr::str_c("wtrep", stringr::str_pad(1:44, 2, "left", "0"))
check_cols <- as.vector(c("finlwt21", wtrep_vars, "cost"))
```

As far as I can tell, the way the data.table is being subset witin the `sapply()` statement, `ce_data[, (check_cols)]`, is returning ONLY the column names. So the `sapply()` function will of course return that the class is `character`.

I played around with the column subsetting a bit..

```
ce_data[, .("finlwt21", "cost")]
ce_data[, .(finlwt21, cost)]
sapply(ce_data[, .(finlwt21, cost)], class)
```

and realized when using a character string only the column names will be returned. When I use symbols (I believe that is what it is called when you exclude quotes) the matrix is returned. Then `sapply` works as intended. `check_cols` is a vector of character strings, so when I try to subset the table it only returns the column names and not the column's data.

There are 46 columns I need to evaluate for the if statement. My question is, how can I alter the `data.table` subset to evaluate these columns as the function intends?

Comment: I think we need: `ce_data[, ..check_cols ]`, which is same as `ce_data[, c("finlwt21", "cost")]`

Comment: `ce_data[, mget(check_cols )]`

Comment: @zx8754 thank you guys. Both answers work as intended.

Comment: or `ce_data[, .SD, .SDcols = check_cols]`, which is effectively the same as `mget` but perhaps more `data.table`-ese.